# Retrieve programmatically SharePoint Online system page html content

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

How can I get HTML content of a SharePoint online page from code, e.g. PowerShell?

I tried `Invoke-WebRequest` with all possible options and nothing worked for me.

It returns another "authentication" page, but I need real page content.

In other words, how to run correctly this PowerShell command?:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Birding/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx'
```

Update: viewlsts.aspx is just an example (and there are better methods to get all site lists), but the actual page I need content of is '_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the approach below, but bear in mind that SharePoint Online:

- Requires authentication. Simply calling Invoke-WebRequest will just return an access denied page.
- Modern pages use lots of client scripts that run *after* the page is served to the client. These scripts first pull in data and *then* render the page contents. Since PowerShell will simply get the initial bear-to-bone page, you won't get what you probably expect to get.

**Install prerequisite PowerShell module**

```
Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser
```

**Authenticate and perform a query to a page of your choice**

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -UseWebLogin 
$HTML_Page_Content = Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod -url /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx -Raw 
Write-Host $HTML_Page_Content
```

`Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod` can be used together with the `-Raw` switch to get contents of *any* SharePoint page. `Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod` is *not* restricted to calling only endpoints located under `/_api/`.

So, instead of doing what you are doing, I suggest simply getting what you want from SharePoint by using [PowerShell PnP commandlets](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/index.html).
For example, to get a list of lists and libraries, simply use:

```
Get-PnPList
```

No need to suffer through the unnecessary web scraping.

Comment: Hi Denis. You probably meant something like `Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod -Url '/_api/web/lists`. Good point. But only in case if I needed only list of lists. The page I actually need is `_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vladilen. Sorry, but I don't understand. do you mean something is wrong with the code I shared? I remember I tested it and it worked exactly as expected. In your case the last line will be `Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod -url /_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx -Raw`.

Comment: It works! But could you please double-check your PnP versions. 
In my environment it worked only with PnP.PowerShell and with -UseWebLogin and with -raw option. Any other combination worked OK for /_api but gave 401 against system page. Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline did not work at all (EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Admin.InvokeSPRestMethod).
I tested with SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline v 3.29.2101.0 and PnP.PowerShell 1.8.0.

Comment: Hi Vladlen. You are right: Turned out I had PnP.PowerShell installed instead. I didn't realize it since I always had issues with the new library. So, I tried PnP.PowerShell 1.7 and 1.8 versions and they both worked fine.